# Combining multiple pngs in a single pdf in python

Tags: python, image, pdf

I am wondering if there is an easy way to combine multiple png images into a single pdf in python. I want each image to be a single page in the pdf. Is pypdf the best library to use for this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: In my experience, ImageMagick has always provided me what I needed with a few lines of code.

Answer (score 4):

```
from PIL import Image

image1 = Image.open(r'C:/Users/uidg3972/Desktop/New folder/Gopi24.jpg')
image2 = Image.open(r'C:/Users/uidg3972/Desktop/New folder/Gopi-1.jpg')
image3 = Image.open(r'C:/Users/uidg3972/Desktop/New folder/SNP_1291.jpg')

im1 = image1.convert('RGB')
im2 = image2.convert('RGB')
im3 = image3.convert('RGB')

imagelist = [im1,im2,im3]

im1.save(r'C:/Users/uidg3972/Desktop/New folder/mergedImages.pdf',save_all=True, 
append_images=imagelist)
```

Comment: Do try the above code, i just tried it. It worked well..... Path of the image should be '/' not '\' symbol. Usually we make a mistake in backslash button try with forward slash..! (Same as URL links in any of web-pages kind of)

Comment: ! pip install pillow and ! pip install image and finally you need .... ! pip in stall img2pdf to run the above code smoothly....! let me if any questions or doubts..!! This is my first contribution, please support and motivate. Thanks ....

Comment: should be imagelist = [im2,im3] otherwise im1 is duplicated

Answer (score 3):

I've got the same problem.

So I've created python function to unite multiple pictures in one pdf.
Code is available at my github page on https://github.com/wizard1989/Unite-multiple-pictures-into-pdf.
It uses "reportlab".

Code is based on answers from the following links:
  [Create PDF from a list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images)
  [Combining multiple pngs in a single pdf in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30154846/combining-multiple-pngs-in-a-single-pdf-in-python)
  [png images to one pdf in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40906463/png-images-to-one-pdf-in-python)
  [How can I convert all JPG files in a folder to PDFs and combine them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42880517/how-can-i-convert-all-jpg-files-in-a-folder-to-pdfs-and-combine-them) 
 https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/01/07/reportlab-converting-hundreds-of-images-into-pdfs/

Here is example of how to unite images into pdf.

We have folder "D:\pictures" with pictures of types png and jpg.
We want to create file pdf_with_pictures.pdf out of them and save it in the same folder.

```
outputPdfName = "pdf_with_pictures"
pathToSavePdfTo = "D:\\pictures"
pathToPictures = "D:\\pictures"
splitType = "none"
numberOfEntitiesInOnePdf = 1
listWithImagesExtensions = ["png", "jpg"]
picturesAreInRootFolder = True
nameOfPart = "volume"

unite_pictures_into_pdf(outputPdfName, pathToSavePdfTo, pathToPictures, splitType, numberOfEntitiesInOnePdf, listWithImagesExtensions, picturesAreInRootFolder, nameOfPart)
```

Answer (score 2):

I've recently found [img2pdf](https://pypi.org/project/img2pdf/), very useful and easy to use... the code is so simply as following (and you can complicate it with some others additional parameters):

```
img2pdf *png -o output_all_pngs.pdf
```

I hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

There's a python port to `WKHtmlToPdf`:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wkhtmltopdf/0.1

Easy to create page breaks between `img` tags in an html doc using css which you can pass to this lib.

http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

Answer (score 0):

This python code converts multiple png images to single pdf in A4 format:

```
i = 0
image_list = []
for x in range(0,5):
    image = Image.open(f'/content/image{i}.png')
    image = image.resize((1250,800))
    im = Image.new('RGB',
              (1240 , 1754), 
              (255, 255, 255))
    im.paste(image,image.getbbox())
    image_list.append(im)
    i+=1

image_list[0].save(r'/content/pdfs.pdf', 'PDF', quality=100, 
save_all=True, append_images=image_list[1:])
```