# png images to one pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, png, fpdf

I have a list of .png images. I need to convert all of them into one pdf, 9 images per page , but not to place them one after another vertically, but fill in all the width, and only then continue to next row. 
Amount of pictures can be different each time (12, ... 15)

I have tried fpdf

```
from fpdf import FPDF

list_of_images = [1.png, 2.png, ... 15.png]
w = 70
h = 60
pdf = FPDF(orientation = 'L')
for image in list_of_images:
    pdf.image(image, w=sizew, h=sizeh)
pdf.output("Memory_usage.pdf", "F")
```

and also wkhtmltopdf

```
template = Template('''<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: row">
        {% for image in images %}
            <img src="{{ image }}" />
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
</body>
</html>''')
list_of_images = [1.png, 2.png, ... 15.png]
html = template.render(images=list_of_pict)
with open("my_new_file.html", "wb") as fh:
    fh.write(html)

p = subprocess.Popen(['wkhtmltopdf', '-', 'Memory_usage.pdf'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
p.communicate(html)
p.wait()
```

but both of them place each picture one under another

Answer (score 9):

Just place each image at required coordinates using FPDF:

```
pdf.image(image, x=50, y=100, w=sizew, h=sizeh)
```

More info on FPDF documentation: [image](http://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is the code which converts a list of images into a pdf. You can also keep a for loop instead of image_1, image_2 etc as below.

```
from PIL import Image

image_1 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\view_1.png')
image_2 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\view_2.png')
image_3 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\view_3.png')
image_4 = Image.open(r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\view_4.png')

im_1 = image_1.convert('RGB')
im_2 = image_2.convert('RGB')
im_3 = image_3.convert('RGB')
im_4 = image_4.convert('RGB')

image_list = [im_2, im_3, im_4]

im_1.save(r'C:\Users\Ron\Desktop\Test\my_images.pdf', save_all=True, append_images=image_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

**disclaimer:** I am the author of `borb`, the library used in this answer

`borb` has a layout system that might help you.
You can use a `PageLayout` if you want to add content to a Page, however the default for Image objects is to always put them on the next line.

You can use an `InlineFlow` object to aggregate objects into a group (and then add that `InlineFlow` object to something, for instance a `PageLayout`)

```py
from borb.pdf import Document
from borb.pdf import Page
from borb.pdf import PageLayout, SingleColumnLayout
from borb.pdf import InlineFlow
from borb.pdf import Image
from borb.pdf import PDF

from pathlib import Path

# create a new Document
d: Document = Document()

# add a new Page
p: Page = Page()
d.add_page(p)

# create a PageLayout to handle content-coordinates/margin/padding
l: PageLayout = SingleColumnLayout(p)

# build an InlineFlow (which will attempt to flow items that are added to it)
f: InlineFlow = InlineFlow()

# add all Images to the InlineFlow
for img_path in [Path("a"), Path("b"), Path("c")]:
    f.add(Image(img_path))

# add the InlineFlow object to the PageLayout
l.add(f)

# store the PDF
with open("output.pdf", "wb") as fh:
    PDF.dumps(fh, d)
```