# How can I convert all JPG files in a folder to PDFs and combine them?

Tags: python, pdf

I have a few 1924 × 2972 JPG files in a folder (/img/). I want to 1) Convert them to PDFs and 2) Combine them into a single PDF. But I am not successful. I am new to python. Please let me know how I can proceed.

```
from PIL import Image
import glob
from fpdf import FPDF #
imagelist = []
for filename in glob.glob('img/*.jpg'): #assuming jpg
    im=Image.open(filename)
    imagelist.append(im)

pdf = FPDF()
# imagelist is the list with all image filenames
for image in imagelist:
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(image, 10,210,297)
pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```

Error:

```
       File "<ipython-input-39-9fb5b6258b5e>", line 1, in <module>
    pdf.image(image, 10,210,297)

  File "/Users/xyz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 150, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)

  File "/Users/xyz/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/fpdf/fpdf.py", line 960, in image
    if not name in self.images:

TypeError: unhashable type: 'JpegImageFile'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second loop, you need to actually reference the path to each jpg:

```
pdf.image(image, 10,210,297)
```

Edit: additionally, I think you just need the path to each image (rather than opening each image using `Image.open`. Try the following:

```
import glob
from fpdf import FPDF #
imagelist = glob.glob('img/*.jpg')

pdf = FPDF()
# imagelist is the list with all image filenames
for image in imagelist:
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(image, 10,210,297)
pdf.output("yourfile.pdf", "F")
```

Comment: Done. Not working yet. Please see the error message.

Comment: Ah. Thank you very much for the edit. It works now. But the images are cutoff and I am not getting the full image as PDF. Am I using wrong dimensions? The images are 1924 × 2972

Comment: I'm not totally sure, I would recommend reading the [docs](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html). How did you come up with the [10,210,297] numbers you're passing to pdf.image()?

Comment: Still trying to figure out stuff. I took at A4 values from here. Not sure whwat 10 is. I just put in a random value.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images

Comment: Try with no arguments, ie pdf.image(image) -- based on the [doc](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/image/index.html), the defaults look sensible

Comment: The doc for image() specifies the ways the size can be specified. Your best bet is to explicitly specify a single dimension, and the other will scale accordingly: pdf.image(image, w=150)

Play with that number until you get what you like. Otherwise if you dig in the docs I'm sure you'll find a way to make it stretch the entire page.

Answer (score 0):

i resolve this problem with fpdf2

```
pip install fpdf2
```

```py
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF(unit="pt", format="A4")
pdf.image(#path image , x, y, width, height)
```

I encountered this problem initially because I just installed fpdf, which this library probably no longer supports.