# FPDF produces empty pages in Python

Tags: python, pdf-generation, fpdf

I wrote Python script that will produce PDFs based on folders with JPEGs. Nothing fancy:

```
import os
from fpdf import FPDF

folders = [ ... here are numbers - folders are numbered ... ]

for folder in folders:
    pdf = FPDF()        
    for fil in os.scandir("parent folder" + str(folder) + "/"):
        pdf.add_page()
        pdf.image(fil.path, w=210, h=297)
    pdf.output("target location/" + str(folder) + ".pdf", "F")
```

This code however results in PDF having every other page blank. Interestingly enough this code:

```
import os
from fpdf import FPDF

folders = [ ... here are numbers - folders are numbered ... ]

for folder in folders:
    pdf = FPDF()        
    pdf.add_page()
    for fil in os.scandir("parent folder" + str(folder) + "/"):
        pdf.image(fil.path, w=210, h=297)
    pdf.output("target location/" + str(folder) + ".pdf", "F")
```

produces file with empty first page and the rest is correct.

I don't see obvious fix for this - looks a bit like a fpdf library. Or is it not?

Comment: Also if you ommit this single add_page call the code fails - just FYI

Comment: Did you try a smaller dimension? It may automatically move to the next page.

Answer (score 7):

Please try by disabling automatic page break mode in fpdf. To do this, please call `set_auto_page_break(0)`. 
I faced this problem and this was my solution. Hope it helps!

```
from fpdf import FPDF 
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.set_auto_page_break(0)
```

For more information, please consult the latest documentation:
http://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/set_auto_page_break/

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I worked around the problem probably still in 2016 and I don't think I have a code that triggered this issue. Can't really comment whether it is correct answer. Thanks for getting back to this, though

Answer (score 3):

The way I solved this was by using the:

```
pdf.set_auto_page_break(0)
```

after i initiated the PDF object and then adding a page before every image insertion. The example code is:

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import os

pdf = FPDF(orientation = 'L') #if you want your pdf to be in Landscape mode
pdf.set_auto_page_break(0)

for i in range(10):
    image_location = os.getcwd() + '\\image_' + str(i) + '.jpg'
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.image(image_location, w=270) #270 used for A4 paper in Landscape orientation
pdf.output('my_pdf.pdf')
```

The PDF file that was generated using the above code had no blank pages.