# Python 3 library to merge any image into PDF

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

In python 3, I have a list of images of various formats (**pdf**, png, jpg, gif), and I'm merging them all into one multi-page pdf.

Using `PyPDF2`, PDF files can be merged. But png, jpg, etc, are not supported. This is very well covered here:
[Merge PDF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444645/merge-pdf-files)

Using `img2pdf`, image types png, jpg, etc, can be converted into PDF and merged. However, it doesn't support input PDF files. Here:
[Create PDF from a list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images)

So, since I can have PDFs, PNGs, JPGs as input, I have use to handle it like this:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
import img2pdf

if not ext == 'pdf':
    with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(images))
else:
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in images:    
        merger.append(pdf)
    merger.write("output.pdf")
```

Question is: do I need these 2 libraries to merge a list of images, including PDFs, into one PDF? Put it another way, is there a library that can have any image as input, including PDFs, and merge them all into one PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a long time since this question was asked, but I wanted to share this answer that I found when I wanted to so the same thing just in case anyone else runs into the issue in the future.
The PyMuPDF module offers similar functionality to that of the PyPDF2 module, but has a few features, including this, that PyPDF2 does not share.
As per the documentation for PyMuPDF, here is a bit of code that should solve this question. It does make use of the PySimpleGUI module for a user interface, but that could be removed if you wanted to do so.

```
import os, fitz
import PySimpleGUI as psg  # for showing a progress bar
doc = fitz.open()  # PDF with the pictures
imgdir = "path-to-picture-directory"  # where the pics are
imglist = os.listdir(imgdir)  # list of them
imgcount = len(imglist)  # pic count

for i, f in enumerate(imglist):
    img = fitz.open(os.path.join(imgdir, f))  # open pic as document
    rect = img[0].rect  # pic dimension
    pdfbytes = img.convert_to_pdf()  # make a PDF stream
    img.close()  # no longer needed
    imgPDF = fitz.open("pdf", pdfbytes)  # open stream as PDF
    page = doc.new_page(width = rect.width,  # new page with ...
                   height = rect.height)  
# pic dimension
     page.show_pdf_page(rect, imgPDF, 0)  
# image fills the page
    psg.EasyProgressMeter("Import Images",  # show our progress
    i+1, imgcount)

 doc.save("all-my-pics.pdf")
```

You can find this code and more about PyMuPDF on the documentation website for the module, which can be found here:
https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-images.html#how-to-make-one-pdf-of-all-your-pictures-or-files

I hope that this helps you or someone who runs into this issue in the future!