# Saving plotly plots in one pdf file

Tags: pandas, plotly

I am trying to save plotly plots generated within a for a loop into one pdf fil, but [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/903) is says we need to pay for it

Is there any updates on this feature? Do we really need to pay to save as pdf?

Comment: As a work around, you can write all of your charts to a ```.png``` [plotly docs](https://plot.ly/python/static-image-export/), then use [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images) to read in all the ```.png``` files and combine them to write a ```.pdf```.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone else still looking for a quick answer 2 years later:

It is possible to export static plotly figures as pdf. Produce a plotly figure, say `fig`. This has the `.write_image` method to export to several formats. Simply do:

```
fig.write_image("your_image.pdf")
```

NOTE: you may need to install `kaleido` (plotly uses it to convert to static images).

`pip install -U kaleido`

Then:

```
fig.write_image("your_image.pdf", engine="kaleido")
```

---

Credits and references:

- [plotly explaining
  it](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/)
- [kaleido](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you do need to pay in order to save as a pdf:

```
py.plotly.image.save_as(fig, filename='file.pdf')

PlotlyRequestError: Hi there! Accounts on the Community Plan can only download PNG and JPEG (raster) images.

To download publication-quality vector images (SVG, PDF, and EPS), please upgrade your account.

UPGRADE HERE: https://plot.ly/products/cloud
```

you can save them as a jpeg or png:

```
py.plotly.image.save_as(fig, filename='file.png')
```