# Python FPDF doesn't support jpg/jpeg

Tags: python, fpdf

I want to transform images to pdf. I think `fpdf` is the best package.
The version is the latest FPDF `1.7.2`. Python version `3.7.2` 64 bit.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
pdf = FPDF() 
pdf.add_page()
pdf.image(r'C:\Users\Bin\Desktop\a\tt.jpg')
```

An error happened:

```
RuntimeError: FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file:
 C:\Users\Bin\Desktop\a\tt.jpg. error: No JPEG marker found
```

The file directory is correct. When I transform the file to a `png`, then it works. It does not work with any other file format such `jpeg/jpg`.How to solve it?
This problem   [Python images to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images) has appeared in stackoverflow. However, all of them does not work for me.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with that specific image. Did you try any other .jpg images? Maybe actually create a jpg image yourself with a graphics app of your choice and try that, just to be sure.

Comment: Did you ask the same question 4 hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56746580/python-fpdf-package-error-no-jpeg-marker-found

Comment: Yes. Initially I found FPDF doesn't work even if I followed every step as others recommended. Then I found FPDF works for 'PNG' file and I updated my question.

Comment: I am sure it  doesn't work for jpg file. I have tried many times

Comment: The source file is here. you can have try! [souce file](https://pan.baidu.com/s/10JSwKyMOmMs_rAIt_X2Dnw). The code is `sify`. It's a Chinese website. Let me know if you can't get in @Mike Scotty

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, for me, it was specific files that did not work. So I re-saved the images as jpg:s in paint and then I could use the file.

I also found that there are a couple of other ways (which I have not tested) that also should fix the problem:

- A [open source](https://github.com/cdefgah/whatsapp-jpeg-repair) project that should fix the error
- I also found this [webpage](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-photoshop-an-unknown-or-invalid-jpeg-marker-type-is-found-error/) with a few different solutions