# Convert jpg files to a pdf

Tags: python, pdf, jpeg, converters

Requirement
I got say 100 jpg files with different dimensions one is 700*900 while another image is 1400*1800. I need to merge all this jpg files into a single pdf and they must be resized to the same dimensions. 
I have tried different things programs and code but couldnt find something that resizes the image.

Comment: What "different things programs and code" did you try?

Comment: Well I tried using Foxit Reader, Foxit Phantom Converter. Some codes here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be already answered here: [Create PDF from a list of images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images)

Comment: Check the link please!

Comment: You should flag this question as a duplicate if you think it is already answered in an SO post.

Comment: Thanks for the response but those I have tried and couldnt meet my requirements. I have images of different file sizes.

Comment: Try this then: https://www.roytuts.com/convert-image-to-pdf-using-python/

Comment: Thanks @Shourov I manually did a image resizing using PIL library and fed the output to fpdf