# How to add a table next a plotly express chart and save them to a pdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly, plotly-python

I have a `dataframe`

```
              a            b   c
0   2610.101010 13151.030303   33.000000
1   1119.459459 5624.216216    65.777778
2   3584.000000 18005.333333    3.000000
3   1227.272727 5303.272727    29.333333
4   1661.156504 8558.836558   499.666667
```

and I am plotting histograms using `plotly.express` and I am also printing a `describe` table with the following simple code:

```
import plotly.express as px
for col in df.columns:
    px.histogram(df, x=col, title=col).show()
    print(df[col].describe().T)
```

Is it possible to add next to each histogram the `describe` and save all the plots (together with their respective histograms) in a single pdf ?

Comment: You can read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27327984/14280520 to save multiple images in a single pdf.

Comment: You can also use reportlab to do it. Look at this tutorial http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/ and the userguide https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf

Comment: None of these solutions worked for me, unfortunately

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by creating a subplot grid, the size of n_columns * 2 (one for the histogram and one for the table. For example:

```py
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

titles = [[f"Histogram of {col}", f"Stats of {col}"] for col in df.columns]
titles = [item for sublist in titles for item in sublist]

fig = make_subplots(rows=3, 
                    cols=2, 
                    specs=[[{"type": "histogram"}, {"type": "table"}]] *3,
                    subplot_titles=titles)

for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    fig.add_histogram(x=df[col], 
                      row=i+1, 
                      col=1)
    fig.add_table(cells=dict(
                        values=df[col].describe().reset_index().T.values.tolist()
                        ), 
                  header=dict(values=['Statistic', 'Value']), 
                  row=i+1, 
                  col=2
                 )
fig.update_layout(showlegend=False) 
fig.show()

fig.write_image("example_output.pdf")
```

In the end, you can save the full fig (6 charts together) as `pdf` using `.write_image()` as explained [here](https://plotly.com/python/static-image-export/). You will need to install `kaleido` or `orca` utilities to do so. The output will look like this (you can of course customize it):

[image]

If you need to save each graph + table on a separate page of the PDF, you can take advantage of the `PyPDF2` library. So, first, you would save each graph + table as a single PDF (as described above, but you would save as many PDF files as numbers of columns you have, not 1), and then you could follow the instructions from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37945454/10354789) to merge them:

Comment: I'd like every histogram with its corresponding table to be on a separate page of the pdf, because this solution would have issues if you want to plot e.g. 10 columns, right ?

Comment: @quant Doesn't that defy this: `Is it possible to add next to each histogram the describe and save all the plots (together with their respective histograms) in a single pdf`? If it doesn't, sorry for bothering you, If it does, then please upvote and accept this answer, and ask a new question that takes care of the mentioned detail.

Comment: @quant `write_image` from plotly doesn't give you much flexibility on that front. As you said, the figure would be saved as a single PDF page. I added a paragraph in the end explaining how you could do that. Essentially, instead of creating 1 single `fig`, you could create + save a `fig` as pdf for each graph + table. Then you could use the `PyPDF2` package to concatenate all the files into one single PDF file, where each row is one single page.