# Why do I get "cannot save mode RGBA" error when using PIL?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am tring to convert images in to a PDF.
I have this code:

```
def convertToPDF(folder, PDFname, deleteLast=False):
    '''
    converts all images in a folder to a PDF. 
    '''
    imageList = []
    for filename in glob.glob(folder + f'/*'):
        image=Image.open(filename)
        image.convert('RGB') # convert to RGB
        imageList.append(image)

    imageList[0].save(f'./' + PDFname + '.pdf',save_all=True, append_images=imageList[1:]) # take the first image and add everything else
```

and I get this error sometimes:

```
 File "c:\Users\felix\OneDrive\Desktop\Programmieren\TelegrammBotProjekt\manganeloAPI.py", line 195, in convertToPDF
   imageList[0].save(f'./' + PDFname + '.pdf',save_all=True, append_images=imageList[1:]) # take the first image and add everything else
 File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 2151, in save
   save_handler(self, fp, filename)
 File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 41, in _save_all
   _save(im, fp, filename, save_all=True)
 File "C:\Users\felix\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\PdfImagePlugin.py", line 156, in _save
   raise ValueError(f"cannot save mode {im.mode}")
ValueError: cannot save mode RGBA
```

Has someone an idea what the problem is and how to fix it?
I thought I'm already converting each image to `'RGB'`. So, why do I get this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`.convert('RGB')` [does not convert between `RGB` and `RGBA`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307290/what-is-the-difference-between-images-in-p-and-l-mode-in-pil); it's meant to convert between `RGB` images and images based on a palette (it's main operations is `P` for palette, `L` for single channel (grayscale) and `RGB` for separate channels).

Instead [you have to be explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166400/convert-rgba-png-to-rgb-with-pil) about making the conversion to drop the alpha channel. From the linked answer:

```
from PIL import Image

png = Image.open(object.logo.path)
png.load() # required for png.split()

background = Image.new("RGB", png.size, (255, 255, 255))
background.paste(png, mask=png.split()[3]) # 3 is the alpha channel
```

You can then use `background` in your image list and save that to the PDF. You've now also explicitly made those images have a white background.

Answer (score 1):

```
from PIL import Image
import os

def convert_images_to_pdf(images_folder, pdf_file):
    images = []
    for file in os.listdir(images_folder):
        if file.endswith(".jpg") or file.endswith(".png"):
            image = Image.open(os.path.join(images_folder, file))
            if image.mode == 'RGBA':
                image = image.convert('RGB')
            images.append(image)
    images[0].save(pdf_file, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:])

convert_images_to_pdf('images', 'images.pdf')
```

Comment: Please add context to your answer to explain how it solves the problem and how it differs from other answers already provided.