# Converting image folders to separate pdf using python

Tags: python, image, pdf, converters

I have folders that contains many jpg files.I want them to convert into PDF files.

Every folder should made into a separate PDF.

Please help I am new to python.

And if possible can I do it in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

[Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327513/create-pdf-from-a-list-of-images)

The best method to convert multiple images to PDF so far is to use PIL purely

Comment: `import os
import img2pdf

with open("output.pdf", "wb") as f:
    f.write(img2pdf.convert([i for i in os.listdir('path/to/imageDir') if i.endswith(".jpg")]))`

Comment: [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45990883/14864237)

Comment: Thanks. can I get separate PDFs from it

Comment: `import os
import img2pdf
dirname = r'C:\Users\Erkin\Desktop\img'
imgs = []
for fname in os.listdir(dirname):
    if not fname.endswith(".jpg"):
        continue
    path = os.path.join(dirname, fname)
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        continue
    imgs.append(path)
x = 0
for img in imgs:
    with open(r'C:\Users\Erkin\Desktop\img\name'+str(x)+'.pdf',"wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(img))
    x += 1`

Comment: here you are tweak and use

Comment: Thank you very much ❤️ I will try it