# How to make a PDF from an online ebook that is displayed page by page?

Tags: python, web-scraping, pdf-generation

I would like to save into PDF books like this one to PDF https://kcenter.korean.go.kr/repository/ebook/culture/SB_step3/index.html that shows a book page by page.

How to do it?

The only thing that I managed so far is to print page by page into a pdf, and then combine separate pdf pages.

Is there a way to do it automatically in Python or other scripts?

Comment: Unfortunately, the referenceed website cannot be accessed by my browsers. Can you provide a valid access?

Comment: Otherwise it is no problem using PyMuPDF to combine any number of input pages on a new PDF page either side by side or any other layout.

Comment: @JorjMcKie I opened it in Waterfox, Edge, Brave, and Vivaldi. Which browser do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the document images directly with `requests` and save to PDF with `PIL`. For example:

```py
import requests
from PIL import Image # pip install Pillow
from io import BytesIO

pdf_path = "doc.pdf"
url = 'https://kcenter.korean.go.kr/repository/ebook/culture/SB_step3/assets/page-images/page-113088-{}.jpg'

images = [
    Image.open(BytesIO(requests.get(url.format(f'{p:>04}'), verify=False).content))
    for p in range(1, 4)  # <-- increase number of pages here (now it will save first 3 pages)
]

# borrowing from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47283224/10035985
images[0].save(
    pdf_path, "PDF" ,resolution=100.0, save_all=True, append_images=images[1:]
)
```

The resulting `doc.pdf` opened in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: How did you find that they are at assets/page-images/page-113088-{}.jpg ?

Comment: @VladislavGladkikh When you open Web Developer Tools -> Network Tab and start loading next pages, you should see the URL with page image there.